# Under what circumstances the sum of all moments (cumulants) converge?

Tags: probability, convergence-divergence, moment-generating-functions, cumulants

Sorry if it is a very basic question. I was wondering under what circumstances the sum of all moments of a random variable converge, i.e. 
$$S_m=\sum_{n=0}^\infty m_n=\sum_{n=0}^\infty \mathbb{E}[X^n] < \infty$$
What about the sum of all cumulants, i.e. 
$$S_k=\sum_{n=0}^\infty k_n=\sum_{n=0}^\infty \frac{d^{(n)}}{dt^{(n)}}log\mathbb{E}[e^{tx}]\bigg|_{t=0} < \infty$$
What about the difference between the two, i.e. $S_k-S_m$?